# Start "chrome" with certain command line parameters?

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome

unfortunately, we have some intranet sites that "insecure" content; thus I really really want to start chrome with "--allow-running-insecure-content".

I "locked" chrome to the unity launcher, later on, I edited 
/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop and added this parameter.

But when starting chrome using the unity launcher ... it doesn't start in that mode.
I had a closer look and saw that the .desktop file even says "--incognito", and no, chrome does start in normal mode.

Long story short: why is the desktop file content not relevant when starting chrome using the unity launcher panel?

Answer (score 1):

you will probably have a local desktop file of chrome in `/home/yourname/.local/share/applications` that overrules the global one.

If you edit that one, it should work.

Comment: Just checked:
~/.local/share/applications$ ls
defaults.list   userapp-transmission-gtk-YMW4OW.desktop
mimeapps.list   usr-usercreated-1.desktop
mimeinfo.cache

No chrome desktop file here?!

Comment: I am not sure what you are writing above :), but I will take a look.. just a minute

Comment: @ErvGunter what is exactly the line after "Exec=" in the desktop file, and what happens if you run it in the terminal?

Comment: The two google-chrome.desktop files that "located" found for me (now) say:
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --allow-running-insecure-content

When I run the same command from a terminal myself, the expect result takes place: chrome comes up and will accept my insecure content ...

Comment: @ErvGunter ....which is good. important is that the local desktop file has the right execute line. Note: chrome has three execute lines: one "native", that runs if you (left) click on the icon, and two optionals (New and Incognito) you will probaly want to edit the first occurence, but more elegant would be to add an extra entry. if so, let me know. N.B. it could be that you have to log in/out after editing the desktop file

Comment: Your final comment helped me to resolve the mystery: there are THREE exec lines within both .desktop files that "locate" would fine for me. Initially, I just jumped to the end of the file and reworked the last one (which is for the "incognito" start).
Now I updated all of them to include --allow... and voila, after running "sudo update-desktop-database", the launcher works like expected! Now, if I would just find the checkbox to mark this question answered?!

Comment: @ErvGunter perfect! glad it works. The checkbox should be on the left, just below the upvote/downvote marks.